# Porque no me funciona UNION en SQL Server despúes de un ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una pregunta sobre SQL Server, al tratar de realizar la unión de estas dos consultas `UNION` me arroja error, ¡no se puede usar UNION después de un ORDER BY?

```
-- consulta 1
SELECT TOP(1)  Nombre, Apellido, Camada, [Fecha Ingreso], 'Mayor' AS MArca FROM Staff
WHERE [Fecha Ingreso] LIKE '2021-05%' ORDER BY Camada DESC

UNION
-- consulta2
SELECT TOP(1)  Nombre, Apellido, Camada, [Fecha Ingreso], 'Menor' AS MArca FROM Staff
WHERE [Fecha Ingreso] LIKE '2021-05%' ORDER BY Camada;
```

Me arroja este error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
-- consulta 1
SELECT * from (SELECT TOP(1)  Nombre, Apellido, Camada, [Fecha Ingreso], 'Mayor' AS MArca FROM Staff
WHERE [Fecha Ingreso] LIKE '2021-05%' ORDER BY Camada DESC) as a

UNION
-- consulta2
SELECT * from (SELECT TOP(1)  Nombre, Apellido, Camada, [Fecha Ingreso], 'Menor' AS MArca FROM Staff
WHERE [Fecha Ingreso] LIKE '2021-05%' ORDER BY Camada) as b
```

Lo que hice fue dejar las dos consultas como subconsultas y les asigne un nombre a cada una.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda el el `Order By` se aplica para toda la consulta, en realidad debería de ser así:

```sql
-- consulta 1
SELECT TOP(1)  Nombre, Apellido, Camada, [Fecha Ingreso], 'Mayor' AS MArca 
FROM Staff
WHERE [Fecha Ingreso] LIKE '2021-05%'
UNION
-- consulta2
SELECT TOP(1)  Nombre, Apellido, Camada, [Fecha Ingreso], 'Menor' AS MArca 
FROM Staff
WHERE [Fecha Ingreso] LIKE '2021-05%' 
ORDER BY Camada DESC;
```

Comment: Puede que no arroje error, pero creo que los resultados no serán los que el OP necesita